# Question Deletion

Tags: support

Do questions get deleted by *the system*?

I've seen quite a few of these lately:

[image]

Ok, so a user maybe deleted a question. But most of the time, the author of the question hasn't been seen on the site for ages.

[Question](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:rWgvFKLIGwwJ:serverfault.com/questions/329690/ad-is-up-or-not%20%22AD%20is%20up%20or%20not?%22site:serverfault.com&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=safari) - [User](https://serverfault.com/users/100561/raj)

How does this happen? Do some questions get auto-deleted because of low views/low score?

Comment: I actually think thats a good question! Could be canonical. I wish more people were that proactive

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/ is interesting and relevant too.

Comment: You should work on earning the 563 rep missing to 10K where you would get access to deleted questions and could check out by yourself :)

Comment: @syneticon-dj I'm on it ;)

Comment: Sadly, 10K+ users see all the deleted questions, whether we want to or not. Just as annoying as all the ads we had to put up with when we first started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`deleted by $a_mod♦ 6 hours ago`

Questions do not auto delete. It was flagged by the system as a "low quality question" and another user as being overwhelmingly useless, a mod agreed, and it was deleted. We've been cleaning up a lot of old crap lately with the new `/review` system.

Unfortunately there will be some collateral damage, as you have noticed.

Comment: Hadn't noticed the new `/review`. Thanks!

Comment: Actually some questions are auto deleted; `age > 1 year && views < 1.5*days && answers == 0`

Comment: @MarkHenderson Also, `age > 30 days && score < 0 && answers == 0 && !locked`. Full details [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/155160).

Comment: @AnnaLear - good to know